# yii2 data provider query takes very long time

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, query-optimization

I am using yii2 data Provider to extract data from database. Raw query looks like this

```
 SELECT `client_money_operation`.* FROM `client_money_operation` 
 LEFT JOIN `user` ON `client_money_operation`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
 LEFT JOIN `client` ON `client_money_operation`.`client_id` = `client`.`id` 
 LEFT JOIN `client_bonus_operation` ON `client_money_operation`.`id` = `client_bonus_operation`.`money_operation_id` 
 WHERE (`client_money_operation`.`status`=0) AND (`client_money_operation`.`created_at` BETWEEN 1 AND 1539723600) 
 GROUP BY `operation_code` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC LIMIT 10
```

this query takes 107 seconds to execute.
Table `client_money operations` contains 132000 rows. What do I need to do to optimise this query, or set up my database properly?

Comment: Do you have any indexes in these tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try pagination. But if you must have to show large set of records in one go remove as many left joins as you can. You can duplicate some data in the client_money_operation table if it is certainly required to show in the one-go result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  mo.*
    FROM  `client_money_operation` AS mo
    LEFT JOIN  `user` AS u  ON mo.`user_id` = u.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `client` AS c  ON mo.`client_id` = c.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `client_bonus_operation` AS bo  ON mo.`id` = bo.`money_operation_id`
    WHERE  (mo.`status`=0)
      AND  (mo.`created_at` BETWEEN 1 AND 1539723600)
    GROUP BY  `operation_code`
    ORDER BY  `created_at` DESC
    LIMIT  10
```

is a rather confusing use of `GROUP BY`.  First, it is improper to group by one column while having lots of non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` list.  And the use of `created_at` in the `ORDER BY` does not make sense since it is unclear which date will be associated with each `operation_code`.  Perhaps you want `MIN(created_at)`?

Optimization...

There will be a full scan of `mo` and (hopefully) `PRIMARY KEY` lookups into the other tables.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can check this.

The only useful index on `mo` is `INDEX(status, created_at)`, and it may or may not be useful, depending on how big that date range is.

`bo` needs some index starting with `money_operation_id`.

What table(s) are `operation_code` and `created_at` in?  It makes a *big* difference to the Optimizer.

But there is a pattern that can probably be used to greatly speed up the query.  (I can't give you details without knowing what table those columns are in, nor whether it can be made to work.)

```
SELECT mo.*
    FROM ( SELECT mo.id FROM .. WHERE .. GROUP BY .. ORDER BY .. LIMIT .. ) AS x
    JOIN mo  ON x.id = mo.id
    ORDER BY ..   -- yes, repeated
```

That is, *first* do (in a derived table) the *minimal* work to find ids for the 10 rows desired, *then* use JOIN(s) to fetch there other columns needed.

(If yii2 cannot be made to generate such, then it is in the way.)